# Flutter: How to edit value in nested jSON - Structure without Dart Objects

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, nested

How can the value in the jSON array
"name": "Holztisch" changed to
"name": "Metalltisch" ?
I do not want to create an instance of a dart class.

Is the solution without dart classes in generall idea?

```
  String eingeleseneJson = '{"bezeichnungElemente":"Auflistung von Tischen",   "tische": [{"id": 1,"type": "einfach", "name": "Holztisch"},{"bauteilId": 2,"type": "mittelklasse","name": "höhenverstellbarer Holztisch"}]}';

  Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(eingeleseneJson);
  var vorhandenFlag = map.containsKey('tische');
  var bezeichnung = map['bezeichnungElemente'];

  debugPrint("testweise Ausgabe");
  debugPrint(bezeichnung.toString());
  debugPrint(vorhandenFlag.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do?

```
String eingeleseneJson = '{"bezeichnungElemente":"Auflistung von Tischen",   "tische": [{"id": 1,"type": "einfach", "name": "Holztisch"},{"bauteilId": 2,"type": "mittelklasse","name": "höhenverstellbarer Holztisch"}]}';

  Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(eingeleseneJson);
  map['tische'][0]['name'] = "Metalltisch";
  // jsonEncode(map);
```

Comment: Many Thanks. Your approach works if you give due position in the array.
map['tische'][0]['name']  = "Metalltisch";
debugPrint(map['tische'][0]['name'].toString());

Comment: Ah, missed that. Sorry. Will update the answer so it is fully correct.